# P/Invoke CryptUnprotectData breaks SqlConnection constructor

Tags: c#, pinvoke, sqlconnection, securestring

I'm attempting to use [`CryptUnprotectData`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/crypt32.cryptunprotectdata) to read a password protected using `CryptProtectData` into a `SecureString` and use that to connect to a database. I can get the correct password out, but trying to create a new `SqlConnection` after that fails with the following:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.
  Source=System.Data
  TypeName=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
       at ProtectedSqlTest.Program.Main() in C:\Git\ProtectedSqlTest\ProtectedSqlTest\Program.cs:line 16
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233036
       Message=The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception.
       Source=System.Data
       TypeName=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()
       InnerException: 
            HResult=-2146233036
            Message=The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception.
            Source=System.Data
            TypeName=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory..cctor()
            InnerException: 
                 HResult=-2147024809
                 Message=The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
                 Source=mscorlib
                 StackTrace:
                      at System.Globalization.TextInfo.InternalChangeCaseString(IntPtr handle, IntPtr handleOrigin, String localeName, String str, Boolean isToUpper)
                      at System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToLower(String str)
                      at System.String.ToLower(CultureInfo culture)
                      at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceCounterLib(String machineName, CultureInfo culture)
                      at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.IsCustomCategory(String machine, String category)
                      at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl()
                      at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.set_RawValue(Int64 value)
                      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolCounters.Counter..ctor(String categoryName, String instanceName, String counterName, PerformanceCounterType counterType)
                      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolCounters..ctor(String categoryName, String categoryHelp)
                      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..ctor()
                      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..cctor()
                 InnerException:
```

It's enough to simply call `CryptUnprotectData` for the `SqlConnection` to fail, the connection itself doesn't need to use the returned `SecureString`.

I'm using the extension methods [from here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8701079/SecureStringExtensions.cs) as described in [this post](http://www.griffinscs.com/?p=12) for my minimal repro:

```
class Program
{
    const string ProtectedSecret = /* SNIP - base 64 encoded protected data here */;
    static void Main()
    {
        // calling AppendProtectedData breaks the following SqlConnection
        // without the following line the application works fine
        new SecureString().AppendProtectedData(Convert.FromBase64String(ProtectedSecret));

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\MSSqlLocalDb;Trusted_Connection=true"))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select 1", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

If i create a new `SqlConnection` *before* I load the password, I can create new `SqlConnection`s fine for the duration of the application as it seems to use the same `SqlConnectionFactory`, but that means as a workaround I have to do something like this at the start of the application:

```
new SqlConnection().Dispose();
```

... which I'd like to avoid.

The following do not help:

- Debug vs Release build
- Debugging in Visual Studio vs running through the command line
- Changing the `CryptProtectFlags` that is passed to `CryptUnprotectData`.
- Removing `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions()` from the protection method.

Windows 10, VS Enterprise 2015, Console Application (.NET 4.6.1)

**UPDATE:** Running the data protection code in another threads gives a similar exception with a different root cause:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.
  Source=System.Data
  TypeName=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
       at ProtectedSqlTest.Program.Main() in C:\Git\ProtectedSqlTest\ProtectedSqlTest\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233036
       Message=The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception.
       Source=System.Data
       TypeName=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()
       InnerException: 
            HResult=-2146233036
            Message=The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception.
            Source=System.Data
            TypeName=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory..cctor()
            InnerException: 
                 BareMessage=Configuration system failed to initialize
                 HResult=-2146232062
                 Line=0
                 Message=Configuration system failed to initialize
                 Source=System.Configuration
                 StackTrace:
                      at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
                      at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
                      at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
                      at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
                      at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
                      at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
                      at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_SwitchSettings()
                      at System.Diagnostics.Switch.InitializeConfigSettings()
                      at System.Diagnostics.Switch.InitializeWithStatus()
                      at System.Diagnostics.Switch.get_SwitchSetting()
                      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolCounters..ctor(String categoryName, String categoryHelp)
                      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..ctor()
                      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..cctor()
                 InnerException: 
                      HResult=-2147024809
                      Message=Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'MACHINE'  Key being added: 'MACHINE'
                      Source=mscorlib
                      StackTrace:
                           at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
                           at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object value)
                           at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.GetConfigRecord(String configPath)
                           at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
                      InnerException:
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you must P/Invoke to `CryptUnprotectData` instead of just using the managed [`ProtectedData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata) wrapper?

Comment: If there is any problem with the P/Invoke code (which seems probable) diagnosing this is easier if you turn on all [Managed Debugging Assistants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d21c150d) ("Exception Settings" from VS). Even that won't diagnose all problems, but it helps.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'd like to avoid handling unprotected data in managed memory.
@stuartd Disposing the `SecureString` doesn't help.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Activating all Managed Debugging Assistants on throw doesn't seem to trigger anything. I wrapped the code in a try/catch and it falls straight into the catch.

Comment: As another debugging tactic, what happens if you do the protect/unprotect on a separate thread? If it works then, this suggests some form of stack/TLS corruption; if it still doesn't work, that's definitely not the issue and other internals may have gotten messed up. (I don't suggest using the separate thread is a *solution*, incidentally.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Interestingly running the data protection stuff in another thread doesn't fix it, but the root cause is slightly different: http://pastebin.com/LCGriSnn

Comment: Does this happen in both 32 and 64-bit builds? A common issue with P/Invoke is field alignment and struct packing which can differ in those cases.

Comment: Yup, identical exception for x86 and x64.

Comment: This is not the point of the question, but is it not pointless to do all of this if you are copying the password onto the managed heap (as you are)?; Also, a simple fix seems to be to just use the built-in append methods which seems a good idea to me.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the secret is in managed memory. `ProtectedSecret` is encrypted, `unmanagedString` and `out_blob.pbData` are zeroed after use and I'm using `SqlCredential` to send the password to Sql Server (in the actual application).

Comment: Just chiming in to say I encountered this issue using the winforms ReportViewer (latest nuget package). The type initialiser failed for System.Runtime.Remoting.Identity, somewhere in the depths of that control. Was fixed by passing null for szDataDescr; I left it as a string.
Oddly, SqlConnection was working fine, and I couldn't seem to break it as described here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was recently experiencing similar symptoms, using the same code from http://www.griffinscs.com/?p=12: any call to `CryptUnprotectData` would lead to an exception in some unrelated code. Interestingly, the failure only occurred on a Windows 10 machine; the same code worked fine on a Windows 7 machine.

I fixed the problem by changing the declarations of the `szDataDescr` parameters in both `CryptProtectData` and `CryptUnprotectData` from `string` to `IntPtr`, and passing `IntPtr.Zero` instead of `string.Empty` in the two calls.

Comment: FWIW, the P/Invoke signature from pinvoke.net uses `CharSet.Auto`, but the Win32 function definition uses `LPWSTR`, which is always Unicode.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly the faulting code is:

```
internal static PerformanceCounterLib GetPerformanceCounterLib(string machineName, CultureInfo culture) {
    SharedUtils.CheckEnvironment();

    string lcidString = culture.LCID.ToString("X3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (machineName.CompareTo(".") == 0)
            machineName = ComputerName.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    else
        machineName = machineName.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    ...
```

the line that calls `ComputerName.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` causes the exception.

You can reproduce the same behavior just calling code

```
new SecureString().AppendProtectedData(Convert.FromBase64String(ProtectedSecret));
string lower = "Something".ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Somehow in the constructor of the [`TextInfo`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/textinfo.cs,500100e2b6916e8b,references) class

```
this.m_dataHandle = CompareInfo.InternalInitSortHandle(m_textInfoName, out handleOrigin);
```

returns invalid data if this is not called before `CryptUnprotectData` function.

This seems like a bug in the framework. You can submit it to Microsoft. In the meantime you can call this line beforehand to prevent the error.

```
"".ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Making that `ToLower` call before the data protection code seems to have the same effect as performing the protection code in another thread. The `SqlConnection` constructor still fails, only with a different root cause: http://pastebin.com/LCGriSnn

Comment: That the actual fault happens in unrelated code strongly points to some form of memory corruption (but likely nota completely wild pointer, because then the fault wouldn't always be in the same(ish) place.

Comment: I don't have access to `pastebin.com`. I can't see the exception. Are you sure you called `ToLower` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`? Parameterless one does not solve the problem. I can successfully create `SqlConnection` after `ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: Yup, copied the line verbatim. I updated my original question with the contents of the pastebin, the exception after `ToLower` is identical to when the protection code is run in a separate thread.

Comment: Very weird... If you call `"".ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` twice that exception disappears as well. Something crazy must be going on there.

Comment: Doesn't seem to for me, same issue after multiple `ToLower`s.

Comment: [This code](https://0bin.net/paste/tqd5OT1+F0kpGjjY#7DHw8q6LwJ1G4AprIkKYHN1Ji4kWat16w87Pu0unOPo) works for me.

Comment: Strange, same `Item has already been added` exception as in the question update for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131152/discussion-between-qqww2-and-jussi-kosunen).